# ffmpeg convert video from specified time period slowly

Tags: video, ffmpeg

For example:
If I convert video like this:

```
ffmpeg -i demo.avi -ss 00:00:05 -t 00:00:15 test.flv
```

it's fast

```
ffmpeg -i demo.avi -ss 00:45:05 -t 00:00:15 test.flv
```

I have to wait a long time before it actually works.

Any way to fix that?

Comment: There is a better place to ask this kind of non-programming questions: http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: I believe superuser would be a better place. We have no idea if the OP is using *nix or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The behavior of `-ss` depends upon where it is placed in the command: as an input or output option. As the ffmpeg documentation states:

```
-ss position (input/output)
When used as an input option (before "-i"), seeks in this input file to position.
When used as an output option (before an outputfilename), decodes but discards
input until the timestamps reach position. This is slower, but more accurate.
position may be either in seconds or in "hh:mm:ss[.xxx]" form.
```

You can also use `-ss` as an input option and an output option which may the provide both speed and (possibly increased) accuracy. See [[FFmpeg-user] Reducing seek time when start time offset (-ss) is large](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2012-August/008767.html) and comments on [Enhancing -ss option](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/ticket/1573) for more examples and details.

Comment: "This is slower, but more accurate." has been removed from ffmpeg documentation (assuming the above is a copy and paste). does it still apply?